# how to create a slide menu ( right to left / left to right ) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i was trying to create a slide menu with jQuery. By default the menu is open when the page loads. and when i clicks on it, Menu slides from right to left. but i don't know how we can push it to its default position. or how we can push it back and forth.

JS Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pPf7N/307/

HTML

```
<aside class="asideMenu">

 i'm the menu click me

</aside>
```

jQuery

```
$('.asideMenu').on('click', function(){
  $(this).css({
   'left':'-200px'
  });
  $(this).html('<span class="openMenu"> open menu -> </span>');
  $('.openMenu').on('click', function(){
   alert('want to push the menu to its default position.');
  });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try change your JS with this one it may be helpful

```js
$('.asideMenu').click(function() {
  var clicks = $(this).data('clicks');
  if (clicks) {
     $(this).css({
   'left':'-10px'
  });
  $(this).html('<span class="openMenu"> open menu -> </span>');
  } else {
     $('.asideMenu').css({
   'left':'-200px'
  });
  }
  $(this).data("clicks", !clicks);
});
```

```css
aside{
  height:900px;
  width:300px;
  position:absolute;
  background-color:#ddd;
  margin:0px;
  padding:0px;
  cursor:pointer;
  transition:all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition:all 0.5s ease;
}
.openMenu{
  color:#000;
  float:right;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="asideMenu">

i'm the menu click me
  
</aside>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a working example, and you can elaborate it to apply according to your needs. Hope it helps.

```js
$('.asideMenu').on('click', function() {
  if ($(this).hasClass('menuClosed')) {
    $(this).removeClass('menuClosed');
  } else {
    $(this).addClass('menuClosed');
  }
});
```

```css
aside {
  height: 900px;
  width: 300px;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #ddd;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: all 0.5s ease;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
.menuClosed {
  left: -200px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<aside class="asideMenu">
  i'm the menu click me
</aside>
```